# Link a profile page to an ethereum address?

Tags: accounts, addresses, meteor

If I have made a page with meteor where a user can login and see his own personal profile page, is it then possible to link that profile page to an ethereum address, so the user can update his profile information which is then saved on the blockchain?. So when a user creates an account, he is also given an address and some ether?

Comment: you can create a smart contract which map the address withe the profile information

Comment: but how do I link the address to a user in  a web interface?

Comment: by using mist or metamask they provide their adresses which you could send to a smart contract to get the identification data

Comment: Is it possible to do with out mist or metamask?

Comment: then how your users will use your dapp (send tx,...)?

Comment: yeah, thats the question...